# Meaning of hog the ball

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "hog" mean in football (soccer) context?

78 min: Chelsea **hog the ball**. The clock ticks on. Everton haven’t really threatened to get back into this game.

Comment: This is a metaphoric extension from ***hog = pig*** - the animal stereotypically associated with greedy eating and selfish bad manners. It's a *slightly* "odd" usage when referring to what a whole football team are doing with the ball, because they're ***supposed*** to "keep possession" as much as possible (there's no concept of being "gentlemanly", and sharing the ball with the opposing side). Hence it's usually derogatory, and I'd normally expect to see it used of a ***player*** who selfishly fails to pass the ball to his team-mates, not a whole team who are playing spectacularly well.

Answer (score 2):

"Hog" in this context means being "greedily possessive". Chelsea is probably carefully passing the ball back and forth, not seriously threatening but making sure Everton gets no chances while time runs out.